# form_for multiple instances of deep nested routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, form-for, nested-routes

I'm putting together a way for teams to enter sporting tournaments. When entering a team, the user must also register *all* the players for that team. My associations & routes are setup as follows:

```
class Tournament < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :teams
  has_many :players, :through => :teams

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :teams  
end
class Team < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :tournament
  has_many :players

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :players
end
class Player < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :team
  has_one :tournament, :through => :team
end
```

(routes.rb)

```
resources :tournaments do
    resources :teams, :only => [:new, :create] do
      resources :players, :only => [:new, :create]
    end
end
```

What I would like to have is one form with multiple Player inputs that are all saved with one click. My current controller & new.html.erb are as follows:

(players_controller.rb)

```
class PlayersController < ApplicationController
    def create
        @tournament = Tournament.find_by_id params[:tournament_id]
        @team = Team.find_by_id params[:team_id]
        @player = @team.players.new(player_params)
        if @player.save
          redirect_to root_path #just return home for now
        else
          redirect_to new_tournament_team_path(@tournament)
        end     
    end

    def new
        @tournament = Tournament.find_by_id params[:tournament_id]
        @team = Team.find_by_id params[:team_id]
        @player = []
        3.times do
          @player << @team.players.new
        end
    end

    private

  def player_params
    params.require(:player).permit(:name, :tournament_id, :team_id)
  end
end
```

(players/new.html.erb)

```
<%= form_for [@tournament, @team, @player] do |f| %>
    <% hidden_field_tag :tournament_id, @tournament.id %>
    <% hidden_field_tag :team_id, @team.id %>
    <% 3.times do %>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :name, "Name: " %>
        <%= f.text_field :name %>
    </p>
    <% end %>
    <%= submit_tag 'Submit', :class => 'rounded_btn' %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

From my understanding I should be trying to create an array of "players" that would contain the names of the 3 players that are entered in the form. This array then gets saved by the create action. Is that the right way to go about it, and what might need changing in my code to set me on the right path?

Thanks.

**FIXED**
Applied the methods in [Ryan Bate's Nested Model Form tutorial](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1)
Also [removed validation for "belongs_to"](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/02/15/rails-5-makes-belong-to-association-required-by-default.html) in Rails 5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FIXED**
Applied the methods in [Ryan Bate's Nested Model Form tutorial](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1)
Also [removed validation for "belongs_to"](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/02/15/rails-5-makes-belong-to-association-required-by-default.html) in Rails 5.0